# Check subject after tabbing to body of mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook, subject

Once I tab to the email's body I want to check the subject.
If equal to a specific text then open a template.

I wrote the part about the template.
The difficult part is using the inspectors to check the subject while  writing the mail.

Code in thisOutlookSession

```vb
Private Sub subject()
 
Dim subject As String
Dim item As Outlook.MailItem
Dim inspector As Outlook.inspector
Dim template As Outlook.MailItem

Set inspector = Outlook.ActiveInspector
Set item = inspector.CurrentItem
subject = item.subject

Debug.Print subject

If subject = "test" Then
    Set template = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:test\test.oft")
    Display.template
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You could create an InputBox for the subject instead of attempting to monitor the subject field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Create three variables on top of `ThisOutlookSession`:

```
   Private WithEvents m_Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
   Private WithEvents m_Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
   Private WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
```

2. Copy the next `Startup` event code in `ThisOutlookSession` module:

```
 Private Sub Application_Startup()
     Set m_Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
 End Sub
```

Or copy only the line `Set m_Inspectors = Application.Inspectors` inside it, if already used for other purposes.

3. Then, copy the next events code in the same module:

```
 Private Sub m_Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
       'Handle emails only:
       Set m_Inspector = Inspector
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()
    If TypeOf m_Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then 
       Set myItem = m_Inspector.CurrentItem '!!!
    End If
 End Sub
```

4. And the `PropertyChange` event to be triggered when pressing enter after writing the subject (or clicking somewhere else: body, To, CC etc.):

```
 Private Sub myItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    Const specSubject As String = "mySubject..." 'use here the subject you need to open the template!
    Const templFullName As String = "C:test\test.oft"
    If Name = "Subject" Then
         If myItem.Subject = specSubject Then
                'do whatever you need...
                myItem.Close False 'probably you want closing the new Email. If not, comment this line...
                With Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(templFullName)
                    .Display
                End With
         End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

Now, manually press `New Email` button and play with the new mail window `Subject`...

Answer (score 1):

The `MailItem` exposes a`PropertyChange(String Name)` event, which fires when the email subject field looses focus (among other).

You can hookup to it, but you need to declare the mail item `WithEvents` at module level.

See an example below:

```
Private WithEvents m_item As MailItem

Sub T()

    Set m_item = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        m_item.Display
    
End Sub

Private Sub m_item_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    If Name = "Subject" Then Debug.Print m_item.Subject
End Sub
```